# Split a string using preg_split

Tags: php, split, preg-split

Im looking for a way to split the following string after each set of numbers using regex.  I am fairly new to this and Im having a hard time understanding how to use the correct regex format.

```
$string = '521158525 Interest Being Subordinated: 521855248 Benefiting Interest: 511589923';

preg_split("/([0-9])/", $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Please post your desired result

Answer (score 1):

To split after each set of numbers, you might use a pattern to match only digits between word boundaries.

Then use `\K` to forget what is matched until so far follwed by matching optional horizontal whitespace chars to not get trailing whitespaces after the split.

```
$string = '521158525 Interest Being Subordinated: 521855248 Benefiting Interest: 511589923';
$result = preg_split(
    "\b\d+\b\h*\K",
    $string,
    0,
    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
);

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 521158525
    [1] => Interest Being Subordinated: 521855248
    [2] => Benefiting Interest: 511589923
)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to add one more flag `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` to function call:

```
<?php
$string = '521158525 Interest Being Subordinated: 521855248 Benefiting Interest: 511589923';

$res = preg_split("/:?\s*([0-9]+)\s?/", $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

var_export($res);
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => '521158525',
  1 => 'Interest Being Subordinated',
  2 => '521855248',
  3 => 'Benefiting Interest',
  4 => '511589923',
)
```

[Share PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=f7607ee4b52054e534fffaf3f0da085c&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: How would I keep the text and split after the numbers?  For example: 
Interest Being Subordinated: 521855248
Benefiting Interest: 511589923